# Flask returning namedtuples as dicts, but not all the time

Tags: python, flask

I have a very small Flask app that looks very much like this:

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['lat', 'lng', 'alt'])

p1 = Point(38.897741, -77.036450, 20)


def create_app():
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/position')
    def position():
        return flask.jsonify({
            'vehicle': p1,
        })

    return app
```

It exists only to feed position data to a web ui. I was expecting that the `Point` namedtuple would be rendered as a JSON array, but to my surprise I was getting:

```
{
  "vehicle": {
    "alt": 20, 
    "lat": 38.897741, 
    "lng": -77.03645
  }
}
```

...which, you know, that's fine. I can work with that.  But then I was writing some unit tests, which look something like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import json
import tupletest

class TupleTestTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        _app = tupletest.create_app()
        _app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app = _app.test_client()

    def test_position(self):
        rv = self.app.get('/position')
        assert rv.status_code == 200
        assert rv.mimetype == 'application/json'
        data = json.loads(rv.get_data())
        assert data['vehicle']['lat'] = 38.897741
```

...and they failed, because suddenly I *wasn't* get dictionaries:

```
>       assert data['vehicle']['lat'] == 38.897741
E       TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

And indeed, if in the test I wrote the return value out to a file I had:

```
{
  "vehicle": [
    38.897741,
    -77.03645,
    20
  ]
}
```

What.

What is going on here? I can't even reproduce this for the purposes of this question; the unit test above renders dictionaries. As does my actual webapp, when it is running, but not when it's being tested. But on another system I appear to be getting arrays from the actual app.

Comment: Note that I've resolved this by using the namedtuple `_asdict` method, so that I'm *explicitly* returning dictionaries, but I am interested in whether this is version skew (it doesn't seem to correlate to flask 0.11.1 vs 0.12.2, for example) or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the sourcecode, this is in the flask's `jsonify.py`:

```
# Use the same json implementation as itsdangerous on which we
# depend anyways.
from itsdangerous import json as _json
```

and in the `itstangerous.py` there is:

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

The `simplejson` library has an option `namedtuple_as_object` which is enabled by default.

---

So when the 3rd party `simplejson` is installed, the app uses it and serializes a namedtuple to a JSON object (a dict in Python).

On systems where that library is not installed, the app falls back to standard `json` and serializes a namedtuple to an array (list).

But if the `simplejson` is installed and imported by flask, the test program imports directly the standard `json` overwriting it and thus changing the behaviour between running and testing.

Comment: This is the cause. To make the tests consistent with the application, then `json` should be imported from `flask`: `from flask import json`

Comment: @VPfB, Thanks for digging into this obscure issue for the root cause!

Comment: @LuisOrduz Using `json` from the `flask` module won't have an impact on the tests..  The issue is in how the data structures are serialized; none of the various `json` modules would be able to reconstitute an array back into the original `namedtuple` (because the labels are lost in the serialization process).